# applied to the enemies lives

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I ran into this problem.

I am creating a game with cocos2d, with Box2D physics. to destroy my opponent I have a tag applied to them (in this case, tag = MONSTER1).

I created a `BOOL _invincible`, and a `int _livesenemy`;

I gave them a number of life by putting in the init method

```c
_livesenemy1 = 2;
```

to destroy the monster that I added

```c
if (!_invincible) {

    if ((spriteA.tag == MONSTER1 && spriteB.tag == LASER2) ||
        (spriteB.tag == MONSTER1 && spriteA.tag == LASER2)) {


        _livesenemy1--;

        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"whine.wav"];

        if (_livesenemy1 == 0) {

            if (spriteA.tag == MONSTER1) [self markToDelete:[NSValue valueWithPointer:bodyA]];
            else [self markToDelete:[NSValue valueWithPointer:bodyB]];

        }

        _invincible = YES;

        {
            _invincible = NO;

        }

        if (spriteA.tag == LASER2) [self markToDelete:[NSValue valueWithPointer:bodyA]];
        else [self markToDelete:[NSValue valueWithPointer:bodyB]];
    }

}
```

the problem is that I only destroys the first monster, and nothing happens to those after

Comment: what have you learned from debugging ?

Comment: How are you creating the monsters?

Comment: Maybe if you change your question's description then more people would have a look at it. Just suggesting...

Answer (score 0):

What i think is happening to you is that since you are setting _invincible = NO;
 just inside there, you are not stopping the game from running that code several times when your objects collide. I recommend you remove that line and schedule a method to set it to NO after the objects have been removed and thus, not colliding anymore.